# How to select from a part of table selected before

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Because of I am collecting data from linked insql server, I should select a part of table and should work on it. But when I want to make conditional selection from a sub-table, I am getting an "Invalid object name error", which should not be because I am setting it with "AS"

```
    SELECT * from (
    SELECT * FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
    where TagName like '%L8.CipPhase%' and DateTime >= DATEADD(HOUR, -12, GETDATE())
    ) as t 
    WHERE t.[DateTime] >= 
    (SELECT MAX(t.[DateTime]) FROM t
    where TagName like '%L8.CipPhase%' and t.[DateTime] < 
    (SELECT MAX(t.[DateTime]) from t
    where TagName like '%L8.CipPhase%' and t.Value = 0))
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a simpler way to express this query.  You should ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing t - which is created as an alias from a subquery, in 2 further sub-queries as tables in a FROM clause - this is not permitted, it thinks `t` there is a real table name. To use it in that manner you would have to create a Common Table Expression (CTE).

e.g.

```
With t as (
    SELECT * FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
    where TagName like '%L8.CipPhase%' and DateTime >= DATEADD(HOUR, -12, GETDATE())
)
    SELECT * from t
    WHERE t.[DateTime] >=  (
                            SELECT MAX(t.[DateTime]) 
                            FROM t
                            where TagName like '%L8.CipPhase%' 
                            and t.[DateTime] < (
                                 SELECT MAX(t.[DateTime]) 
                                 from t
                                 where TagName like '%L8.CipPhase%' 
                                 and t.Value = 0
                            )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

use temp table :

```
SELECT * into #Temp FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
where TagName like '%L8.CipPhase%' and DateTime >= DATEADD(HOUR, -12, GETDATE())
declare @DateTime DateTime


SELECT @DateTime=MAX(t.[DateTime]) 
FROM #Temp
where TagName like '%L8.CipPhase%' and t.[DateTime] < 
(SELECT MAX(t.[DateTime]) from #Temp
where TagName like '%L8.CipPhase%' and t.Value = 0)    

select * from #Temp 
    WHERE t.[DateTime] >= @DateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

T is not a table, it's an alias for the subquery. So in the where condition, you need to include the table name where you are retrieving the max date.

```
   SELECT * from (
    SELECT * FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[History]
    where TagName like '%L8.CipPhase%' and DateTime >= DATEADD(HOUR, -12, GETDATE())
    ) as t 
    WHERE t.[DateTime] >= 
    (SELECT MAX(t.[DateTime]) FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[History] t
    where TagName like '%L8.CipPhase%' and DateTime >= DATEADD(HOUR, -12, GETDATE() and t.[DateTime] < 
    (SELECT MAX(t.[DateTime]) from [Runtime].[dbo].[History] t
    where TagName like '%L8.CipPhase%' and DateTime >= DATEADD(HOUR, -12, GETDATE() and t.Value = 0))
```

Comment: If you just change the t alias to the original table, the sub-query predicate `DateTime >= DATEADD(HOUR, -12, GETDATE())` is then not included in the further uses of it. The intention appears to be re-use, so the predicate would also have to be included.

Comment: Noted, using CTE is an efficient way but this is an alternate, I have included the corresponding where condition as well.